# Google App Engine base and subclass gets

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to have a base class called MBUser that has some predefined properties, ones that I don't want to be changed. If the client wants to add properties to MBUser, it is advised that MBUser be subclassed, and any additional properties be put in there.

The API code won't know if the client actually subclasses MBUser or not, but it shouldn't matter. The thinking went that we could just get MBUser by id. So I expected this to work:

```
def test_CreateNSUser_FetchMBUser(self):
    from nsuser import NSUser
    id = create_unique_id()
    user = NSUser(id = id)
    user.put()
    # changing MBUser.get.. to NSUser.get makes this test succeed
    get_user = MBUser.get_by_id(id)
    self.assertIsNotNone(get_user)
```

Here NSUser is a subclass of MBUser. The test fails.

1. Why can't I do this?
2. What's a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered GAE has a solution for this. It's called the PolyModel:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass

Answer (score 3):

Models are defined by their "kind", and a subclass is a different kind, even if it seems the same.

The point of subclassing is not to share values, but to share the "schema" you've created for a given "kind".

A kind map is created on base class `ndb.Model` (it seems like you're using `ndb` since you mentioned `get_by_id`) and each kind is looked up when you do queries like this.

For subclasses, the kind is just [defined](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py?r=302#2751) as the class name:

```
@classmethod
def _get_kind(cls):
  return cls.__name__
```